# Update values in ArrayList recursively

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a simple class Person:

```
private String name;
private String surname;
List<Person> subPersons;

//getters & setters
```

how I can recursively update values in List? For example I have List with size = 3. in the List(1) I have another list with size 2. I need a recursive method for update values in Person class in every child Lists.

P.S. sorry for my English :)

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function which will update persons with any depth of children:

```
public void update( Person person )  {
     // Do whatever you want on that particular person
     ...

    // Update sub persons (assume subPersons maay not be null, only empty)
    for( Person subPerson: person.subPersons ) {
        update( subPerson );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void recursiveUpdate(Person parent) {

    // Modify name and surname
    // parent.setName(...); parent.setSurname(...);

    List<Person> children = parent.getSubPersons();

    if ((children == null) || children.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    } else {
        for (Person child : children) {
            recursiveUpdate(child);
        }
    }

}
```